# XAMPP Apache server not working on internal network

Tags: apache, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on my local laptop (Vista) and it works fine. Apache and MySQL are running as services, and I can get to both http://localhost/ and http://192.168.2.2/ without any hassles.

However, if I try accessing the server from another laptop on my internal network by typing in the http://192.168.2.2/ ip address, it <del>errors</del>times out. What am I missing here?

When I run Port Check, I get the following:

```
Service              Port   Status
==============================================================================
Apache (HTTP)          80   Program: C:\xampp\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Apache (WebDAV)        81   free
Apache (HTTPS)        443   Program: C:\xampp\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe

MySQL                3306   Program: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
\mysqld.exe
```

and when I try telnetting to localhost port 80, that works too. My httpd-vhosts.conf file contains the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.2.2>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: My first thought: "Not programming related". Maybe better suited at serverfault.com

Comment: "It errors out"... What error are you receiving when you try to access 192.168.2.2 from another machine?

Comment: Sorry, I should fix that. It times out, not errors out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered via help at ServerFault.com

The problem was that the Windows Firewall had port 80 blocked. To fix this, I opened Windows Firewall, clicked Change Settings, went to the Exceptions tab, and then "Add Port". I set Name to "Web Server (TCP 80)", Port Number to 80, and Protocol to TCP and that was it.